# typeSel.get() not working

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

def add_item():

    def create_rec(item):

        def saveREC():

            print typeSel.get()

        label2=Label(add_win, text="select item type:").pack()

        #radio buttons creation
        typeSel = StringVar()
        R1 = Radiobutton(add_win, text="meat", variable=typeSel, value="meat")                  
        R1.pack( anchor = W)

        saveBttn=Button(add_win, text="recognize this item in the future", command=saveREC).pack()

    def saveEntry():
        item=entry.get()
        a,typeVar=fridgePK.item_recognition(item)
        if a==True:
            print item, " is saved to ", typeVar

        #if item isn't recognized then user can add item to recognition list        
        if a==False:
            create_rec(item)

    add_win=Tk()

    entry=Entry(add_win, width=30)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()

    saveBttn=Button(add_win, text="add item", width=25, command=saveEntry)
    saveBttn.pack()

    add_win.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to save an item to a file corresponding to the selected radio value named typeSel. I attempt to call the radio value through typeSel.get() but nothing is happening. Why is that? When I pull the function out by itself it works fine but not in here.

Comment: There are some serious problems with your code. What you need to do is use `class` (yes,start from scratch!). Also,don't define methods within methods.

Comment: Sorry I've only been learning python for a month. I know my program isn't the best nor the prettiest, but everything else besides typeSel.get() works. I don't really know how defining classes work neither. Will my code never work like this?

Comment: It will work but its not good practice. If you are just making this for learning purposes & there is no time limit, you might wanna consider doing what I suggested

Comment: I'm reading about classes, instances, and methods right now. I think I bit more than I can chew when I started this. I have about another 300 lines of code written like what you see above. its atrocious but so far works. Can I do both? fix this and re-write a new one with classes?

Comment: Yes you can but you really need to learns how indentation works in python

Comment: how do I indent a group of text? both on here and on my texteditor?

Comment: give 4 spaces. Both here & in your text editor. You can maybe start with [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Mf0h3HphEA) tutorials

Comment: i did, but do I have to indent by pressing 4 spaces for each line. suppose I have 25 lines of miss-indented texts, do I have to press space 100 times?

Comment: Here you can just select the whole code & press Ctrl+K

Comment: im on a mac, googel says I have to press command + ], pretty cool. so how would you fix the typeSel.get() problem?

Comment: there are a lot of undefined variables in your code. Start by fixing that

Comment: oh, I omitted those the shorten the code length. I can add them in if it makes things more clear.

Comment: could you add **[minimal working code](http://www.sscce.org/)**?

Comment: the funny thing is. I tried to do a minimal working code and it for some reason worked. but I have no idea why. And when i reimplemented the rest, it stopped working again. let me try again

Comment: how is this? if its still too long... let me try some more

Comment: fridgePK is another file where data is stored. I deleted that so now its even more minimal. Item_recognition(item) is from a function in fridgePK. it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually was happening was that it was not able to get the value of radiobutton & hence printing a *blank*. Maybe you didn't notice it but if you print something else in that method,you would have noticed

Since I couldn't use `fridgePK.item_recognition(item)` . I took test vales for them. Tell me if this works:

```
from Tkinter import *

def add_item():

    def create_rec(item):

        def saveREC():
            print "hola"#for test purpose
            print typeSel.get()

        label2=Label(add_win, text="select item type:").pack()

        #radio buttons creation
        typeSel = StringVar()
        R1 = Radiobutton(add_win, text="meat", variable=typeSel, value="meat")                  
        R1.pack( anchor = W)
        typeSel.set('meat')

        saveBttn=Button(add_win, text="recognize this item in the future", command=saveREC).pack()

    def saveEntry():
        item=entry.get()
        a=False
        typeVar="hello"
        if a==True:
            print item, " is saved to ", typeVar

        #if item isn't recognized then user can add item to recognition list        
        if a==False:
            create_rec(item)

    add_win=Tk()

    entry=Entry(add_win, width=30)
    entry.pack()
    entry.focus_set()

    saveBttn=Button(add_win, text="add item", width=25, command=saveEntry)
    saveBttn.pack()

    add_win.mainloop()

add_item()
```

Comment: It works! why are you such a god? how many years do I need to learn to do what you can do? are you a professional?

Comment: I'm a student actually.& it doesn't take much time. Just continue to do what you are doing,you will learn quickly enough ;)

Comment: @user3634772: Also, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: what did you change exactly? I re-implemented the code into my original file but my typeSel.get() now returns 1 instead of the good type. yet it works fine in your code

Comment: @user3634772: I used the `set` with radiobutton.

Comment: @user3634772: a little change in there. Kindly check that

Comment: yes its working now. The function by itself works, but if I call from my main.py file then it doesn't.

Comment: That's why i said: use `class`. The code would be more understandable & readable. This type of solution is just temporary

Comment: ok i will. you are a student? highschool? college? wanna recommend a good book on python or just general programming?

Comment: I'm in college. The link I posted earlier(of the tutorial videos) was what got me started, after that, it was all stackoverflow ;)